# Python: leap year - olympic games

Tags: python

What i am using now
I need help displaying the host of the olympic games after the leap year check

```
def isLeap(year):
    # your code (note comment under original post for the statement order)
    if(year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0):
        return True
    elif(year % 400 == 0):
        return False
    elif(year % 100 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# just write every pair of year and city in this format
host = host = {1986 : "Athens",1900 : "Paris",1905 : "St.louis",1908 : "London",1912 : "Stockholm",1920 : "Anstwerp",1924 : "Paris",1928 : "Amsterdam",1932 : "Los Angeles",1936 : "Berlin",1948 : "London",1952 : "Helsinki",1956 : "Melbourne-Stockholm",1960 : "Rome",1964 : "Tokyo",1968 : "Mexico",1972 : "Munich",1976 : "Montreal",1980 : "Moscow",1984 : "Los Angeles",1988 : "Seoul",1992 : "Barcelona",1996 : "Atlanta",2000 : "Sydney",2004 : "Athens",2008 : "Beijing",2012 : "London",2016 : "Rio",2020 : "Tokyo",2024 : "Paris",2028 : "LA"}

userInput = int(input())
if(isLeap(userInput)):
    print(host[userInput])
```

Any Help is much appreciated,
thanks

Comment: Remember to read your text after posting, so you can fix formatting mistakes.

Comment: the datetime module could be of some assistance. You might want to check an almanac for the locations of the olympic games.

Comment: Your two elif-clauses are in the wrong order.

Comment: Okay, so what is your *question*?

Comment: how can i add code to show where the olympic games were held that leap year?

Comment: First, your years are all off by 4. Tokyo was 1964 and 2020, not 1968 and 2024. That being said, your code should work.

Comment: @Woody1193 I think the years are ok.

Comment: @Woody1193 Not my question, I've been trying to help op.

Comment: @DimK True, it's not really germane to the conversation. Just through me off a little >_<

Comment: @Codi.no your code appears to do what you're telling us it should do so can you provide an example of input and what output you would expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all the years with olympic games, associated with the corresponding city in a dictionary like so:

```
host = {2004 : "Athens", 2008 : "Beijing", 2012 : "London", 2016 : "Rio"}
```

Then, once your leap year function has evaluated a year as a leap year, simply access the value of that year-key in the dictionary.

```
>>> print(host[2012])
London
```

A complete solution would look something like this:

```
def isLeap(year):
    # your code (note comment under original post for the statement order)
    if(year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0):
        return True
    elif(year % 400 == 0):
        return True
    elif(year % 100 == 0):
        return False
    else:
        return False

# just write every pair of year and city in this format
host = {2004 : "Athens", 2008 : "Beijing", 2012 : "London", 2016 : "Rio"}

userInput = int(input("Enter Year: "))
if(isLeap(userInput)):
    print(host[userInput])
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209826/discussion-on-answer-by-dimk-python-leap-year-olympic-games).